# How to get distinct values out of a collection with where condition in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

How to get distinct values out of a collection with where condition?

For Example, I have Worker class, which contains status and workerId along with other fields,
Here i want to retrieve distinct workerId's which has status="ACTIVE";

I have made enough googling but could not find any solution

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Edit

Sorry guys i didn't put my question properly.
I want this to be done using morphia not by using mongodb native query.

Can this be done using MapReduce?
Help me out please!

Comment: Searched Google for "mongodb and distinct": http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/  Isn't this what you want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in posting,

```
BasicDBObject dbObject=new BasicDBObject();
dbObject.append("status","ACTIVE");
```

this `dbObject` will act as a where condition,

```
DBCollection dBCollection = datastore.getCollection(MyEntity.class);
List id=dBCollection.distinct("id",dbObject);
```

This ID list will contains all distinct ID's whose `status="ACTIVE"`

Answer (score 0):

[distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) is supported as a command instead of a query (not sure why). Try the below

```
db.runCommand ( 
    { 
        distinct: 'name-of-collection',
        key: 'worker-id',
        query: { 'status': 'ACTIVE' }
    } 
)
```